# How to change focus of a jsp's <form:input /> via JavaScript with a barcode reader?

Tags: javascript, input, focus

In a JSP I have two  fields. When the page is loaded, the focus is set to the first field. When I input the value from a barcode reader, it "presses" the enter key so the form is submitted.

I need to use the barcode reader to input the first value in the first field, then focus the second field so I can scan the second value and only then submit the form.

The javascript function I'm trying to use is this:

```
    $().ready(function() {
    $("#serialNumber").val("").focus();
    $("#serialNumber").keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            $("#serialClient").val("").focus();
        } else {
            $("#button").submit;
        });
    }
});
```

The form submit button is:

```
<button type="submit" class="submit">Submit</button>
```

But if I change this button type to "button" I can submit the form any longer.

How can this be fixed?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need watch for the click on the button to then submit the form. You can check out the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/beckje01/demYs/5/) or the quick example below.

```
 $('#submitBtn').click(function(e){
     $('#formID').submit();
 });
```